# Xamarin "Attempting to JIT compile method "

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Suddenly my app is chucking these errors on a NuGet package that was recently updated to 64 bit support.

> Attempting to JIT compile method `Refractored.Xam.Settings.Settings:GetValueOrDefault<bool> (string,bool)` while running with `--aot-only`. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.

Its stymied me.

It's called here:

```
    public static bool RememberMeSwitch
    {
        get { return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(CacheKeys.RememberMeSwitch, false); }
        set { AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(CacheKeys.RememberMeSwitch, value); }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: @slaks i have updated the question. It's basically when I call the Settings. Works in the simulator and Android

Comment: What is the source of RememberMeSwitch?

Comment: Do you intend for your application to use JIT or AOT-only?

Comment: I am currently investigating and will see if it is an issue in the NuGet or if it is a regression somewhere else.

Comment: I have the same problem, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. You must enable generic type sharing in the settings. It is on by default. I did not document this and I will add it to the readme:

[image: Enable generic value type sharing]

Answer (score 1):

I newer versions the setting to enable Reflection capabilities is called "Enable the Mono interpreter":
[image]